# How to add the UserId parameter to the query string of a XmlUrlDataSource in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have an aspx that returns XML data using the query string parameter UserId. This UserId should be the SharePoint current User.

I create the datasource and dragged to the page, but i don't know how to add the parameter to the datasource, so that it sends the current User Id. I tried to add the parameter in the datasource parameters grid but when the aspx gets called it always uses the default value and not the current user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding a parameter through the context menu of the control (i.e. the DataFormWebPart) in design menu.